# looking for a better way to sync databases

Tags: database, synchronization

I have an app (vb.net) which collects data from users and stores the data locally on their laptop until they sync it up with a central SQLServer 2008 database. The sync needs to be in both directions. So right now, I have a timestamp on each record that gets set when that record gets updated. Then I compare times on the records to see which is more recent. If a record on the laptop is more recent than the one on the central DB, the laptop record gets sent up. And if the record on the central DB is more recent than the laptop, that record gets sent down to the laptop.

I have several hundred thousand records spread over about 15 tables. It is taking 3 to 4 minutes to run through all of them if you are local on the network. The problem really gets worse for remote users. It takes them 20 to 30 minutes to sync. via VPN.

I have about 5 users doing this and they all need to maintain the same information with each other by way of the central database. They all sync to the central DB, not with each other.

Is there a better way to check every record other than comparing timestamps?

- Note that only a handful of records (5%) change each time they sync, but I don't know which ones it may be. It could be any of them. So I have to check all of them.

Thanks.

Comment: check out SymmetricDS (FOSS, java)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion timestamps are not the way to go for determining which records to send to the other party.

Although they might be "ok" for conflict resolution, time differences on synchronization parties (computers), might cause records to be skipped from sending out, causing real problems.

Myself I use an identity column (on the server side) on one specific table to generate sequence nr's, and in every transaction, I get a new sequence number, and assign this to all updated/inserted rows of the other tables that need synchronization.

Now when a client requests synchronization, it provides the server with the latest 'sequence' it received during last synchronization or 0 if it is the first time.

The server would send only those records that have a greater sequence number, and then determines what the highest sequence number was on those records it actually sent to the client, and give this number to the client for next synchronization requests.

In my scenario, conflict resolution is done on the client, because all business logic is their anyway, and this means, that the client always receives updates first, before it start to send theirs.

Because you use one newly generated sequence number for every transaction, you maintain referential integrity during each synchronization, but to make sure that's actually true, 
you need to determine the currently highest sequence number before you start to send synchronization data, and never retrieve any records higher then this number, because otherwise you could break referential integrity.

This because, some other thread might have committed inserts of Orders and OrderItems after you already looked up the Orders but not the OrderItems, by which you have OrderItems in your outwards synchronization package without the Order.

For deletions, I use a IsDeleted column, and the server holds records for some period before they really get deleted.

When clients insert data, I give them feedback of what (primary) keys that records where given, etc.. etc..

Well, there is so much more to this then I can mention here, but here are some key thoughts for you that you should watch carefully:

How to prevent:

- Missing records
- Missing deletes
- Double inserts
- Unnecessary sending of records (I use a nullable field LastModifierId)
- Input validation
- Referential integrity
- Conflict resolution
- Performance costs (choose the right indexes, filtered unique indexes are great for keeping track of temporary client insert identities of records, so they might also be null, you need these to prevent double inserts)

Well good luck, hope this gives food for thoughts..

Comment: Thanks. This is a lot of info. But is it fast?

Comment: Depends on how you implement it, understanding how to optimize your database schema/indexes is important for speed, but it can be. You only send changed data, that would be your biggest win.

Comment: OK, Thanks. I'll see what I can do with it.